# Passing a method reference of a nullable type idiomatically

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface:

```
interface A{
 fun test(foo:Int,bar:Int)
}
```

And I have a nullable reference to an implementation of A

```
val aImpl:A? = .....
```

I then have a  higher order function which receives a nullable function of signature same as test

...

```
fun higherOrder(f:((a:Int,B:Int)-> Unit)?){ ... }
```

How do I pass a reference of test function to higherOrder? For example this doesn't work:

```
higherOrder(aImpl::test)  // aImpl is nullable
higherOrder(aImpl?::test) // I'd expect reasonably this to work, but syntax is invalid
```

This works, but it feels kinda hacky and long. And I was trying to avoid an extra lambda.

```
higherOrder(aImpl?.let{it::test})
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: You have to check for null: no way around it. It's not a hack, it's a normal flow. Also the code you say works doesn't compile.

Comment: That'd need to be  aImpl?.run{ ::test } . But it does remove the extra it. Thank you :) Didn't think of it.

Comment: @dyukha You're right, should be lambda in let.My bad

Comment: You are welcome. `And I was trying to avoid an extra lambda.` Are you concerned about performance? in the generated code there will be no lambdas, since `let` is an `inline`-function.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there are a few ways of accomplishing this

```
interface A{
 fun test(foo:Int,bar:Int)
}

val aImpl:A? = .....

fun higherOrder(f:((a:Int,B:Int)-> Unit)?){ ... }


// Not very Kotlin
if (aImpl != null) higherOrder(aImpl::test)

// Kotlin, but weird
higherOrder( aImpl?.let { it::test } )

// Very kotlin, maybe a bit more overhead in understanding
higherOrder { a, b -> aImpl?.test(a, b) }
```